# Too many records dumped into SQL Server 2016 database

Tags: sql-server-2016

Another programmer tried to fix our Powershell script and ended with a few million extra records in one table associated with one machine. Most records seem to be grouped by date and duplicated. Am able to find most of them with 'Group by' expression, but can't flag them with an Update mytable set PartEval = 'Dup1' where ..... etc.

Group By Code below works and gives me those that are duplicated. Most that don't belong are duplicated by DateRan column

```
 SELECT DateRan, PartEval, count(*) as cntBad
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE MachineNr = @MachineNr 
   AND (DateRan >= some_date 
   AND DateRan <= Some_Date_Plus2)
 GROUP BY DateRan, PartEval
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

 UPDATE mytable
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DateRan, PartEval, COUNT(*) AS cntBad
               FROM MyTable
               WHERE MachineNr = @MachineNr 
                 AND (DateRan >= some_date 
                 AND DateRan <= Some_Date_Plus2)
               GROUP BY DateRan, PartEval
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

I tried code above and `WITH` CTE expression, also tried to update my_table `Where Exists` (code above). but it only sets Dup1 to every record with the date range set, instead of only those the Group By expression finds.

Any suggestions how to find and flag these that have duplicate dateran (a Date Time column)?

Answer (score 0):

Handling duplicates is something you would typically do using `row_number`.

You assign a row number to each group of duplicates, specifying the ordering to determine if you want to keep the lowest/earliest or highest/newest row.

This might do what you want

```
with d as (
    select dateran, parteval,
      Row_Number() over (partition by dateran, parteval order by dateran) as dupenum
    from MyTable
    where MachineNr = @MachineNr 
    and DateRan >= some_date and DateRan < Some_Date_Plus2
)

update d set parteval=Concat('Dup',dupenum-1)
where dupenum>1
```

i'm not sure without seeing any sample data if you should partition by both columns or just the dateran column, no doubt you can figure that part out.

Of course you could just delete the duplicate rows

```
delete from d
where dupenum>1
```

Comment: Many thanks. That did the trick. I wanted to flag the bogus data for now then delete later.